# Почему знаковое переполнение это UB?

Tags: c++, неопределённое-поведение, overflow, переполнение, c++20

Почему знаковое переполнение это UB, ведь с C++20 всегда используется 2's complement, а значит результат однозначно определен?

Comment: Стандарт предписыват подчинятся арифметике по модулю "2^битность" только для unsigned. Для signed такой однозначности нет. Сделано так по разным причинам, в том числе для возможности оптимизации, когда компилятор будет расчитывать что когда `X` больше `Y` то `X + 1` тоже больше `Y`

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan я не про модуль говорю, а про https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: 2'complement это способ представления отрицательного числа. Какая будет применятся к нему арифметика, зависит от реализации. Поэтому несмотря на представление числа в 2'complement операции над ним являются UB при переполнении.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan какие бывают реализации сложения кроме сложения "в столбик", которое описывается по ссылке?

Comment: Самый банальный пример уже приводил, например где-то в коде у вас сначала вычисляется `X`, затем `Y`, после чего стоит условие, к примеру `if (X + Y > 0) ...`. Для signed значений, компилятор может выбросить операцию сложения, и просто сравнить `X > 0` и `Y > 0` (предполагая, что если число уже положительное, то складывая с другим положительным отрицательное не может получится). Также есть железо, которое выбрасывает исключение при переполнении, и для unsigned компилятор добавляет в код проверки на переполнение, а для signed нет (для оптимизации).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan это следствие наличия UB, а не его причина. Правда ли, что единственная причина UB в знаковом сложении это добавление пространства для оптимизаций?

Comment: Думаю, современные компиляторы используют слишком много оптимизаций, полагающихся на UB при знаковом переполнении, чтобы просто так взять и отказаться от них. Ну, или авторы стандарта/компиляторов хотят чтобы _программист страдал_ :)

Comment: @wololo почему некоторые UB типа порядка вычисления некоторых выражений усмирили, а это -- нет? Более строгие гарантии не ломают старый код, только разработчикам компиляторов проблема, получается

Comment: Похожие вопросы: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57363324, https://stackoverflow.com/q/55468807

Comment: @Ivan43, давно известно, С++ хорош тем, что создает *новые рабочие места*. И похоже, что всех причастных к телу это перманентно устраивает

Comment: @Ivan43, но замедляют.

Comment: можешь пример здесь посмотреть:
https://happydapps.com/ru/article/cpp-signed-overflow

Answer (score 9):

До C++20 стандарт языка допускал три способа для представления знаковых целых чисел:

- Signed magnitude
- Ones' complement
- Two’s complement

Начиная с C++20 для представления целых чисел может использоваться только two’s complement. Автором этого изменения является некто *Jean François Bastien* (e-mail: jfbastien@apple.com). Предлагаемые изменения в конкретных пунктах стандарта языка, мотивацию и обсуждения изменений вы можете найти в документе [P0907R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r4.html).

Помимо всего прочего, товарищ JF Bastien предлагал в случае переполнения знакового целого при выполнении арифметических операций усекать результат по правилам модулярной арифметики (т.е. поступать также как и для беззнаковых величин). Но встретил сильное сопротивление со стороны комитета по стандартизации:

> This paper proposes the following:
> ...
>
> - *Status-quo* If a signed operation would naturally produce a value that is not within the range of the result type, the behavior is undefined. The author had hoped to make this well-defined as wrapping (the operations produce the same value bits as for the corresponding unsigned type), but WG21 had strong resistance against this.

Основные возражения комитета [таковы](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r4.html#r0r1):

- Проблемы производительности. Оптимизатор не сможет предполагать, что переполнение никогда не происходит, и выполнять оптимизации, вытекающие из этого предположения.
- Возникают сложности при реализации таких штук как санитайзеры.
- Google считает, что 90% всех переполнений является багом, поэтому модулярная арифметика для знаковых целых не нужна.

Вопрос на stackoverflow.com с примерами оптимизаций, когда оптимизатор считает, что переполнения при знаковой арифметике не возможны: [Is there some meaningful statistical data to justify keeping signed integer arithmetic overflow undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56047702)

Comment: Больше всего в этой ситуации с UB раздражает то, что на реальном железе (x86, arm, mips, arc) ничего странного при знаковом переполнении не происходит, в самом деле, просто результат усекается.

Answer (score 6):

Потому что в противном случае затрудняются оптимизации. Рассмотрим, к примеру, такие формулы:

```
x > y + 2
x - 2 > y
```

Математика нам говорит, что эти формулы эквивалентны. Но если разрешить знаковое переполнение - они эквивалентными быть перестанут!

Answer (score 5):

Потому что оптимизация.

В си и плюсах довольно агрессивная оптимизация, касающаяся арифметики над целыми числами, а необходимость обрабатывать ситуации с переполнением её напрочь убивает, так что никуда они не уберут UB.